# Altium overlapping room on top and bottom layer

Tags: pcb-design, altium, multi-layer

I am trying to do a 4 layer PCB (The 2nd layer is Ground and 3rd layer is VCC). While I am placing overlapping rooms on top and bottom layers, then after placing the rooms, when I try to move a room on a layer, it moves some tracks and vias on the other layer as well. How to layout rooms / components in multi layer PCB this way? I mean I want to move the room on a layer without disturbing vias and tracks on the other layer.

The RED is the top layer and BLUE is the bottom layer.

[image]

Comment: Why do you wish to layout rooms?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I can definitely hide the rooms and drag individual component, but its easy to move a whole set of components and tracks using room, especially when you laid up the components and then need to move the whole section little left/right.

Comment: Is there really no solution to this Problem? I just encountered this Problem where I want one Multi-Channel Design on the Top and one on the Bottom. However if I move either the Top or Bottom Room Definition, Tracks on both sides are being moved. I mean... I just cannot believe that this is intended.

Comment: @SimonK. I could not find any satisfactory answer of this question. So I had to remove the concept of "room" from my brain while in PCB designing mode :( If you find anything, let me know. It's really irritating.

Comment: Try moving the room while in single-layer mode.